# Обрезание содержимого до последнего(указанного) символа

Tags: javascript

Имеется `<input type="file" />` при добавлении файла я получаю значение его прямой директории на компьютере, т.е. C:/asd/... и т.д.

А мне хотелось бы получить **ТОЛЬКО** имя выбранного файла, как это можно организовать?

**vanilla js**

```js
document.querySelector("input[type='file']").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
```